# How to optimize pandas queries with non-integer multi-level interval index?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, intervals

I often need to query large pandas dataframes and I am looking to find the most optimized way to perform these queries. I deal with Linearly Referenced Systems (highways). Most of the roadway attributes are stored as linear events and they are indexed by route id and beginning and ending milepost. What I am looking for is querying the roadway attributes for a specific milepost. The following is a sample of a dataframe that stores the roadway attributes:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [pd.Index(['FC','FC','FC','FC','OWNER','OWNER','OWNER','OWNER']),
     pd.Index(['RID1','RID1','RID2','RID2','RID1','RID1','RID2','RID2']),
     pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays([0,1,10,11,0,1,10,11],
                                  [1,2,11,12,1,2,11,12])])
idx.names = ['Item','RID','MP']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
df.index = idx

Out[24]: 
                     Value
Item  RID  MP             
FC    RID1 (0, 1]        1
           (1, 2]        2
      RID2 (10, 11]      3
           (11, 12]      4
OWNER RID1 (0, 1]        5
           (1, 2]        6
      RID2 (10, 11]      7
           (11, 12]      8
```

and the following is an example of a query dataframe:

```
query_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Item':['FC'  ,'OWNER','FC'  ,'OWNER','OWNER'],
        'RID' :['RID1','RID1' ,'RID1','RID2' ,'RID2' ],
        'MP'  :[0.2   ,1.5    ,1.6   ,11.1   ,10.9   ]})

Out[26]: 
    Item   RID    MP
0     FC  RID1   0.2
1  OWNER  RID1   1.5
2     FC  RID1   1.6
3  OWNER  RID2  11.1
4  OWNER  RID2  10.9
```

I have tried two approaches:

1) First Approach:

```
for i in range(10000):
    query_df['Value'] = query_df.apply(lambda r:df.Value.loc[r.Item].loc[r.RID].loc[r.MP],axis=1)

Wall time: 1min 18s
```

2) Second Approach:

```
df = df.sort_index()
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([query_df.Item,query_df.RID,query_df.MP])
query_df.index = idx
query_df = query_df.sort_index()
for i in range(10000):
    query_df['Value'] = df.Value.loc[idx]

Wall time: 16.8s
```

While the second approach has a good performance, it won't work if the intervals are float and not integers. For instance, if I change the df to the following:

```
Out[24]: 
                     Value
Item  RID  MP             
FC    RID1 (0, 1.2]      1
           (1.2, 2]      2
      RID2 (10, 11]      3
           (11, 12]      4
OWNER RID1 (0, 1]        5
           (1, 2]        6
      RID2 (10, 11]      7
           (11, 12]      8
```

the first approach still works fine but the second approach returns the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Correct query results:

```
query_df
Out[18]: 
Item   RID    MP  Value
0     FC  RID1   0.2      1
1  OWNER  RID1   1.5      6
2     FC  RID1   1.6      2
3  OWNER  RID2  11.1      8
4  OWNER  RID2  10.9      7
```

Any ideas how to apply the second approach to float intervals or any other approaches that works with float intervals and have a time similar to the second approach?

Versions:

```
print(pd.__version__)
0.23.4
print(sys.version)
3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27456